# Perl running cmd with backspace

Tags: perl, command, stdout, interactive, backspace

When I run an application (wget.exe) using cmd, the output contains backspace characters that make the output display nicely. But when I run it in perl using `open` or backstick with 2>&1, it prints out the output in a different way that doesn't use backspace. How can I still keep the backspace display?

Comment: Running on Windows?  Does the output from `wget` change when the output is a file or pipe compared to a terminal?  It sounds as if it does.  If so, you may have to work out how to persuade `wget` that it is writing to a terminal.  On Unix, you'd use a pseudo-tty (or `pty`) for the task; the output of `wget` would be redirected to the `pty` device and the other process would read what `wget` wrote and process appropriately.  Double check to see if there's an option to `wget` to do the job automatically.

Comment: Thanks, the output is different from the terminal output. I'm also looking for a way to do this for Windows.

Comment: I can spell Windows: U, then N, then I, then X.  No?  Oh, then maybe I can't help further.  Sorry.  (That's why it was a comment and not an attempt at an answer.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure wget is outputting the display differently when its not going to STDOUT.  Why do you want to preserve the backspace?

Comment: Try: wget www.bing.com 2>&1 | less

Comment: I'm curious why you're calling wget instead of using a perl module? Then you woudn't have to worry about parsing output...

Comment: I used UserAgent to download files but it stops halfway and the file is corrupted sometimes. So I tried to switch to an external tool to do the same job.